# Unable to create users in OpenAM console

Tags: active-directory, openam

I am unable to create the user using OpenAM console. I am using Active Directory as User profile Data store. I can able to view the users and Groups present in AD but can't able to create Users in console.

In log file I am getting error like,

In `amConsole.error` I got the below error.

> "Chrish|user|/|Plug-in com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Repo
>   encountered an ldap exception. LDAP Error 53: The LDAP server is
>   unable to perform the specified
>   operation."id=amAdmin,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com e830efb407eb01cd01
>   "Not Available" SEVERE dc=example,dc=com
>   "cn=dsameuser,ou=DSAMEUsers,dc=example,dc=com" CONSOLE-4
>   amConsole.error "Not Available"

In `amConsole.access.log` i got the below error:

> Chrish|user|/ id=amAdmin,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com e830efb407eb01cd01
>   "Not Available" INFO dc=example,dc=com "cn=dsameuser,ou=DSAME
>   Users,dc=example,dc=com" CONSOLE-1 amConsole.access "Not Available".

Help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

1) it might not be a good idea to use OpenAM console (or other OpenAM APIs) for provisioning (this is what you do) ... it requires a good understanding of the OpenAM data store / IdRepo concept, especially if multiple data stores are used.

2) if OpenAM writes the 'unicodePwd' attribute to AD this has to be done via LDAPS

-Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at OpenIDM as a solution here? It's designed for the cases where you need to handle user creation and those changes (CRUD) can be applied to your directory (AD). It has a basic UI and you can hit the REST interface as well.

I agree with Bernhard that the console is a tough place to accomplish this kind of activity.